# Help launching TEST ICO

Tags: rinkeby

at the moment I am learning to do my test ICO on rinkeby test net. i am doing all the coding on my windows computer, but my node is running on a Linux server. My goal is to do a fully functional ICO on rinkeby testnet that my friend would be able to participate in.

At this point in time by watching tutorials online I have managed to deploy the coin to the rinkeby network and it’s address is 0x1a41Ec0118aA521d01Ca881B91C751a4e14ba447 But what follows next? How do I make an actual coin offering? Do i need to deploy new smart contract at the same address? Do i need to modify the existing contract and deploy it again? What are my next steps? P.S. I need to finish the ICO without using the Remix IDE

Code of my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import ‘zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol’;
import ‘zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol’;

contract TestToken is StandardToken, Ownable {

  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  uint public decimals;

  function TestToken() public{
    name = “Test Token”;
    symbol = “TST”;
    decimals = 18;
    totalSupply_ = 1000000 * 10 * uint(decimals);
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenZeppelin (which you've used for your token) has "standard" Crowdsale contracts you could use. Generally best practice is for the Crowdsale and Token contracts to be separate with the Crowdsale "controlling" the Token (i.e. the Token is mintable and the owner is the Crowdsale).

There are other ways to do crowdsales, but if you're after a simple example OZ approach above should be more than sufficient.

Comment: So you are saying that I should create a new contract "Crowdsale" using OZ template standard crowdsale, then transfer all available tokens to that contract and then do an ICO from the crowdsale contract?